# How do you set up a open() or die statement using the program argument as input?

Tags: perl, filehandle

In my current homework assignment, I am trying to open a file using the open or die condition. I am supposed to open a file, then list its contents line by line, and then apply a regex to it (this part is irrelevant right now). Here is some code so far...

```
my $filename = '<>';
open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "Could not open file, please enter a proper file handle";

while(<>){
  print $_;
}

close $fh;
```

Thanks for helping guys... I look forward to an answer to my issue. I know it might be a simple answer but I'm still new to perl so anything is appreciated.

Comment: `my $filename = <>; chomp($filename);`

Answer (score 2):

`@ARGV` contains the program's arguments.

```
@ARGV == 1
   or die("usage\n");

my ($qfn) = @ARGV;

open(my $fh, "<", $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

while (<$fh>) {  # Sets $_
   chomp;          # Remove the line feed from $_.
   print("$_\n");  # Re-adds the line feed and prints the line.
}
```

or

```
...

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
   chomp($line);      # Remove the line feed from $line.
   print("$line\n");  # Re-adds the line feed and prints the line.
}
```

The thing is, Perl has a special handle (`ARGV`) that reads from the files whose paths are found in `@ARGV` (or from STDIN if not arguments were provided). This is the default handle used by `<>` (meaning that `<>` is short for `<ARGV>`), so all you need is the following:

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   print("$_\n");
}
```

---

Technically, all you need is the following:

```
while (<>) {
   print;
}
```

The above is equivalent to the following:

```
print while <>;   # Also one line at a time.
```

You could even use the following:

```
print <>;         # Reads all the lines, then prints them.
```

That said, one normally wants to transform the input in some way before printing it back out, and removing the training line feed is usually helpful to that.

---

I called the variable qfn for qualified file name, meaning a relative or absolute path that includes a file name. This is what you truly accept, rather than just a file name.